# Continuous-time vs Discrete-time Fourier transform

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, dtft

*case 1*) to calculate the Fourier transform of discrete-time signal(**sampled signal**) we use **Discrete-time Fourier transform**.

but my question is:

*case 2*) if I consider that discrete-time signal as continuous-time signal which is multiplied by Dirac comb(impulse train) then we produced a **sampled signal but in continuous mode**
now we apply **continuous Fourier transform** to this signal.

notice that in both case we have the **same** sampled signal(the only difference: in first case signal is in discrete form and in second signal is in continuous form)

**the result of "*case 1*" is equal to result of "*case 2*"?**
if not,what does cause it?

Comment: it ***is*** equal if you cross your i's and dot your t's and make sure your scaling is correct.  

perhaps someone has asked this question before and there is an answer.  i feel like i have been here before.

Comment: here is [half of your answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34153/discreteness-and-periodicity-in-fourier-transform/34156#34156).  this shows what happens to your spectrum when you uniformly sample with a [Dirac comb function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) (a.k.a. "impulse train").  you will see that the spectrum becomes periodic forever, just like going around the unit circle on the z-plane forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward to show. Let $x[n]$ be a sampled version of a continuous-time signal $x_c(t)$:

$$x[n]=x_c(nT)\tag{1}$$

The DTFT of $x[n]$ is defined by

$$X(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]e^{-jn\omega}\tag{2}$$

The CTFT of the signal

$$x_c(t)\cdot\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x_c(nT)\delta(t-nT)\tag{3}$$

is given by

$$\begin{align}\mathscr{F}\left\{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x_c(nT)\delta(t-nT)\right\}&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x_c(nT)\mathscr{F}\left\{\delta(t-nT)\right\}\\&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x_c(nT)e^{-jn\Omega T}\tag{4}\end{align}$$

which equals $(2)$ with $x[n]=x_c(nT)$ and $\omega=\Omega T$ being the normalized angular frequency.

And now I found [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/36527/4298), which is pretty similar but also asks about some background.